# How do you cast NSValue pointerValue() to UIView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I wrap a UIView in an NSValue so I can use it as a key in a dictionary.

```
let viewValue = NSValue(nonretainedObject: myView)
```

I need to know how to get the UIView back out and cast appropriately when using:

```
viewValue.pointerValue()
```

It is returning a UnsafeMutablePointer< Void > and I need to cast that to a UIView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're storing it as a `nonretainedObject` value, you should fetch it the same way.

```
let viewValue = NSValue(nonretainedObject: myView)
viewValue.nonretainedObjectValue
```

The other would pair like this:

```
let viewValue = NSValue(pointer: myView)
viewValue.pointerValue()
```

Comment: `nonretainedObjectValue` is a property not a function, so it should be `viewValue.nonretainedObjectValue`. Also note that it comes back as an optional `UIView?`, so it would probably be good to wrap it in an optional binding statement: `if let view = viewValue.nonretainedObjectValue { ... }`

Comment: @MikeS  @Ian MacDonald  `var view:UIView = UIView()

let viewValue = NSValue(nonretainedObject: view)
var dict = [viewValue:view]

var view2:UIView = dict[NSValue(nonretainedObject: view)]!` works fine why we need to these all thing can you please tell me.

Comment: @codester If `viewValue` is just being used as a dictionary key, then I can't think of a reason offhand why you'd need to pull the `UIView` back out of it. Maybe @bstahlhood is also using `viewValue` elsewhere...

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I was typing pretty quick and didn't notice, I guess. I updated the accessor. I'll leave the conditional checking up to the reader, though; I was just answering the question.